# C# Adding years and days in a single DateTime variable

Tags: c#, datetime

Am I missing something simple?
I am trying to calculate a date 17 years and 364 days before the given date.

Is there a way to do this without converting everything into days?  I am trying to avoid dealing with leap years.  I am doing the following:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(tId2);
string tId4a = Convert.ToString(tId4);
var age1 = tId4a.Substring(0, 2);
int age2 = Convert.ToInt32(age1) - 1;
DateTime sub1 = date.AddYears(-age2);
```

I was hoping to do something simple like:

```
DateTime sub1 = date.AddYears(-age2) + date.AddDays(-364);
```

I am being told that I cannot use the '+' in the DateTime.

Sorry, but I am new to this.  The reason the age2 variable is used is because at times that value will change.  But, the 364 should be consistent.  I am creating something to test a date boundary.

Did I overlook something simple?

Thanks.

Comment: `date.AddYears(-age2).AddDays(-364);`

Comment: I think you meant to chain them, but I'm not completely sure `date.AddYears(-age2).AddDays(-364);`

Comment: As an aside, and I am only saying this because you said you are new to this... Your variable names are not descriptive at all and it is difficult to figure out what the variables represent by name alone.  Try to make your variable names more descriptive

Comment: I am wondering if you would not be better off with `date.AddYears(-18).AddDays(1)`.  This would be less sensitive to leap years than subtracting 17 years and 364 days.

Comment: There is some other code here that raises flags for me, although not related to the main of your question.  You seem to have some variable tId4, which you convert to a string tId4a.  What was tId4 to begin with?  the contents of a user input textbox?  Converting to string, grabbing the first two characters and then converting to int32... looks suspicious.  It would be better if you told us what tId2 and tId4 are to start with and what you want to get to.  I think we could give you a much better way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks all!  I figured I was overlooking something.

Comment: As for the tID4 - I am loading a spreadsheet into a data table and trying to work with that data to create two new data tables that will export out into 2 excel files.  I plan on reviewing the points here and I really appreciate everyone's input.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesCraig be sure to mark an answer checked if it worked for you. It will help others who come to your question later on who want to figure out what answer you used that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really sounds like you want to go with tid4 years ago, but go to the next day after that.

The way you are doing it, is that you subtract 1 from that to get age2.  Then you subtract that many years, and you also subtract 364 days from your date.  This will be more sensitive to leap years.  If the resulting date happens to be between Jan 1 and Feb 28 of a leap year, you will end up with one day later than you wanted.

364 is a very suspect number.  I tend to think you are using that to mean "the number of days in a year minus one".  But the number of days in a year is not always 365.  In leap years, the number of days is 366.  In such years, subtracting 364 is not 1 day less than a year.  It is actually 2 days less than a year, so you would be off.

What you really should do, if I am reading you correct, is to just subtract the number of years, then add one day back in.

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(tId2);
string tId4a = Convert.ToString(tId4);
int age = Convert.ToInt32(tId4a.Substring(0, 2))
DateTime sub1 = date.AddYears(-age).AddDays(1);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, I need both 'sides' around the date in the spreadsheet so this will definitely help.

Comment: No worries, James.  Just do not subtract 364 days.  Better to subtract a year and add a day back in.

Answer (score 4):

What you do is you add the "date `age2` years ago" to the "date `364` days ago".

Instead do this:

```
DateTime sub1 = date.AddYears(-age2).AddDays(-364)
```

This at first subtracts the years and then subtracts the days from the *resulting* value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add dates, but you can certainly chain method calls together

```
date.AddYears(-age2).AddDays(-364);
```

This is for all intents and purposes the same thing as trying to add them together.

Comment: You should explain why the answer you have given works, and why what OP tried did not.

Comment: Self-explanatory answers are valid.

Comment: While I do understand your answer on first sight, someone might not. I won't downvote your answer, but it's usually preferable to include some context for other readers so they can *understand* why their attempt didn't work.

Comment: And I'm actually perfectly fine with that. What really frustrates me though, is that I think you're 100% correct. So I then use your logic and tell that to someone else who does just what I did. And then I get scolded because the rules say self-explanatory answers are fine. I just never win tbh.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is valuable to mention that `DateTime` is an object, and that `.AddYears()`, `.AddDays()`, etc all return a new `DateTime` object which is why you cannot add them together like primitive types. So when you run:

```
DateTime sub1 = date.AddYears(-age2).AddDays(-364);
```

`date.AddYears(-age2)` returns a new object, and then `.AddDays(-364)` is using the new `DateTime` object and not the date instance.

For more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx